# Angular cannot load assets folder with angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Opened a new angular 4 project and I'm trying to load my assets folder and I get error

> net: ERR_ABORTED

[image]

I'm trying to get fonts.css or any file from the assets folder and I get this error. what I'm doing wrong?

I tried this way and I still the project not compile

```
  "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "assets/fonts/fonts.css",
        "assets/stylesheets/ionicons.min",
        "assets/stylesheets/fonts/fonts.css",
        "assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css",
        "assets/stylesheets/isotope.css",
        "assets/stylesheets/venobox.css",
        "assets/stylesheets/sinister.css",
        "assets/stylesheets/slimmenu.css",
        "assets/stylesheets/main.css",
        "assets/stylesheets/main-bg.css",
        "assets/stylesheets/main-responsive.css"

    ],
```

Comment: read up on how to include assets / external scripts / stylesheets in angular.cli. Take a look at the `.angular-cli.json`

Comment: it is under `assets/fonts/fonts.css`

Answer (score 2):

During your build process with `angular-cli` a production folder is created, therefore your path to local files (like assets, fonts, stylesheets or plugins / scripts) will change.

Angular CLI has a build in way to handle this, by specifiying these paths in the `.angular-cli.json`.

There you will find a part that looks like this:

```
...
"apps": [
    {
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "assets": [
            "favicon.ico",
            // place the relative paths to your assets, like images, here
        ],
        "styles": [
            "assets/fonts/fonts.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
            "assets/javascript/libs/common.js"
        ],
        ...
     }
  ],
  ...
```

Hope it helps.

Update: Using wildcards / globs for including multiple stylesheets in a certain folder is not possible:

> We're not looking at adding glob support to styles, because loading order is relevant. Instead, just make a single file that imports everything in the order you want and put that in the styles array.
>   Source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3069

As suggested, you should look into `SASS` or `LESS`, create one main stylesheet which includes all of your stylesheets in the correct order, and include the generated css file.

Comment: hey, what to write into assets?  the whole path to assets?

Comment: the relative path from the `angular-cli.json` to your specific file / folder

Comment: @AdirZoari Edited the example above

Comment: Wait a moment, for `fonts.css` it has to go to the styles array, i will edit it once again to make it clearer

Comment: really I need to do for each style I want to include from assets??

Comment: @AdirZoari to be honest, i'm not sure, i can try if you want and come back to you ;) but in best practice you want to bundle your custom styles anyway so you end up only with one stylesheet (and probably one for every framework / plugin you use). The same with scripts.

Comment: okay i will wait to answer from you, back to me when you can, i apperciate.

Comment: @AdirZoari i know that you can include a whole folder of assets, but i will try with styles

Comment: can you please check how I include javascript,jquery files also?

Comment: @AdirZoari the same way. your config should already have all of these arrays to see an example. i edited my answer with an example and an explanation why you have to specifiy all stylesheets singlehanded.

Comment: still not working. if I have image into images folder and I want to write into main. css background:url("assets/images/img_1.jpg") not working also

Comment: your main.css seems to be in the `stylesheet` directory, so your example is not a correct relative path to your image (and has in this case nothing to do with angular or the cli), try `url("../images/img_1.jpg")` for this example.

Comment: so what path I need to give it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to write your `css`  in `styles.css` and in `component.css`
```

However, if you want to use external `css library` like `bootstrap` then install it with `npm` and pass reference in `angular-cli.json` styles section.